# Detecting if a group of numbers has a strong correlation

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I have a group of numbers which are stored in binary which can be integers or floats. I want to determine which of the two formats the numbers are in. All the numbers in a group should have a pretty strong relations, as they represent a data point. (eg height of a person, miles between cities, interest percentage for a loan...). Manually this is a pretty easy job, as numbers which make sense as floats often does not make sense as integers.

Is there any algorithm for determining this? I am unsure what this is called, but to me it sounds like a statistics problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of the series: once with all data interpreted as integers, and a second time with the data interpreted as floats. Then choose the representation that yields the smallest variance.